# How can I show a whole table in a query criteria if I press enter

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have a students' table, and I also have a query for their gender. When I type male in the query it'll show me all the male students and whenever i type female it'll show me all the female students. Is it possible that if I press enter without typing a specific gender, I would get to see all of them? If so, How do I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIKE and wildcard.

`SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender LIKE [enter gender] & "*";`

All you have to enter is F or M or nothing.