# In SQL, how do I return 'ALL' as M and F

Tags: sql, ms-access

everyone. I believe this is my first time posting on here. 
I actually started learning a bit about SQL while on an internship. I decided to work on a little project during an internship using the forms feature in Access which user-friendly buttons and search fields to search through a large table of data.

So far everything is going pretty well, except for I'm stuck on one thing. There's a *listbox* item that I have where the results can filter by gender. There are three options: M, F, ALL.

If either *M* or *F* is selected, the option they select is transferred to the code with no problems. The issue is, I want to also be able to select ALL, which  would would **ideally** shoot back the results for both M and F.

How can I make it so that if ALL is selected, my code understands this to be a request for M and F?

Thank you for any insight you might be able to offer!

Erick

Here's the code I used:

SELECT Count(*) AS Amount_From, Count(*)*100/(SELECT Count(*) FROM FY2018) AS Percent_From
FROM FY2018

WHERE gen IN ([Forms]![Form1]![ComboGen]) /* This is the part I have a question about. The options on the form are "M, F, ALL", but "ALL" is not actually value that exists in the table. If I could set a variable like ALL = M + F, that would probably solve my problem. Is there a way to do that in SQL?*/

AND coo =[Forms]![Form1]![TxtCountry] /* coo is country of origin */

AND aaa Between nz([Forms]![Form1]![TxtAgeMin],0) AND nz([Forms]![Form1]![TxtAgeMax],500) /* aaa is age at arrival */

AND doa Between Nz([Forms]![Form1]![DateBegin],#1/1/1900#) And Nz([Forms]![Form1]![DateEnd],#12/31/2200#); /* doa is date of arrival */

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Congrats on your first question!!

Can you tell us in your question a little bit about what you are reading and researching to help yourself so far?  What have you tried?

(I'm not an access expert these days so I'll let someone else help you with that part)

Comment: Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138801

Answer (score 2):

You can do the filtering like this:

```
where gender = @gender or (@gender = "ALL")
```

`@gender` is what you are passing into the query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to make sure that I understand it. In the table of data that this is querying, there is a column that deals with gender. It's labeled 'gen'. The only values that I have in that column are M and F. How can I make my code understand that ALL = M + F. I'm assuming I can't assign a variable in SQL. Thanks!

Comment: @user3531: Edit your question with your current query (the code from SQL view), then we can be more specific.

Comment: @user3531 . . . This code should return the entire table when `@gender` is `"ALL"`.  That appears to be your intention.

Comment: @user3531 In your case, `@gender` might be replaced with `Forms!YourFormName!YourListBoxName`